# PHP Latvian array of words sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a question.. I have an array of Latvian words (i.e `Agita Matīsa`, `Āris Matisovičs`, `Baiba Matisone`), and I need to sort this array in alphabetical order...
So I dont know how to do it, because it's not a usual latin alphabet...
can onyone help me?
here is some code, which describe how I get this array:

```
foreach($pacienti as $key => $val)
                        {
                            $person = array();
                            foreach($val as $p)
                            {
                                $person[] = $p; 
                            }
                            $person = array_unique($person);


                            foreach($person as $pac)
                            {
                                if ($key != null)
                                    $div_patienti .= "<div id='".$key."' class='filial_r15'>".$pac."</div>";    
                            }

                        }
```

**UPD1**

here is array value:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "agita&nbsp;matīsa&nbsp;080569-11863" } array(1) { [0]=> string(35) "aija&nbsp;matīsa&nbsp;240938-11562" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your locale to Latvian, and then sort your array using the SORT_LOCALE_STRING flag.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'lv_LV');
sort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

Alternatively, you could use `usort` with `strcoll` as a locale-sensitive string comparison if you want to do some sort of custom sorting based on a complex key structure.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'lv_LV');
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strcoll($a['key'], $b['key']);
});
```

PS - if this is coming out of a database, probably best to set your DB to handle the (Latin-2?) character set / collation so that you can pull your data out in the correct order.

Comment: I have been added setlocale to my php script... but it seems that sort doesnot work=(

Comment: all data is getting from db, but I can't modify it collations, or something else in it=(

Comment: @vladimir - Are you sure you're using a sortable array?  `sort` requires a 1-dimensional array... http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php  - if you have more dimensions, you have to use `usort`

Comment: please see my updated question, for clear, how looks my array

Answer (score 0):

You should change collocation to utf8_unicode_ci which sorts Latvian accent symbols correctly. If You can not modify database it can be done on-the-fly:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8_latvian_ci';

SELECT keyword
FROM ctest
ORDER BY CONVERT(keyword USING ucs2) COLLATE ucs2_latvian_ci,
CONVERT(keyword USING ucs2) COLLATE ucs2_bin ASC;
```

Source:
http://laacz.lv/2010/10/28/ka-ieks-mysql-sakartot-latviesu-burtus-pareiza-seciba/